# Using pyinstaller on c compiled python code

Tags: python, cython, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert one single c file into an executable with pyinstaller. Now the reason why I want to compile with pyinstaller is because of the fact, that the exe file is supposed to be run on both a mac as well as a windows machine.

Now, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can include Cython/C modules in a Pyinstaller executable.

*However, Pyinstaller is not suitable for your goal of making a single executable that works on Mac and Windows.* [From the first question of the Pyinstaller FAQs:](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ)

> **Can I use PyInstaller as a cross-compiler?
>    Can I package Windows binaries while running under OS X?**
>
> No, this is not supported. [...]

It seems like you've fundamentally misunderstood what Pyinstaller does: it packages a Python script with Python and its libraries to allow you to use the Python script without having to install Python separately. To do this though it needs to package a version of Python specific to the platform, and so the executable will only work on the same operating system that it was created on.

In addition, it deals with compiled libraries (like Cython modules) by [zipping them up and the extracting them into a temporary folder when run](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works). Therefore, *even if* Pyinstaller somehow managed to bundle two versions of Python to work on both Windows and Mac your C compiled module would still only be compiled for a single platform, so by doing it they way you describe you've actually made your code less portable.

I don't believe there are any obvious tools to do what you're asking.

Comment: Wait a second, is it not possible to have pyinstaller bundle my python script into an exe. That can both run on mac and windows?
That's how I interpreted it:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-folder-program-works

Comment: No, Pyinstaller can bundle your program into an executable that can run on Windows or on Mac, but not both in the same executable.